# how to use the input with pandas to get all the value.count linked to this input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe looks like this:

```
Index(['#Organism/Name', 'TaxID', 'BioProject Accession', 'BioProject ID', 'Group', 'SubGroup', 'Size (Mb)', 'GC%', 'Replicons', 'WGS',
    'Scaffolds', 'Genes', 'Proteins', 'Release Date', 'Modify Date',
       'Status', 'Center', 'BioSample Accession', 'Assembly Accession',
       'Reference', 'FTP Path', 'Pubmed ID', 'Strain'],
      dtype='object')
```

I ask the user to enter the name of the species with this script :

```
print("bacterie species?")
species=input()
```

I want to look for the rows with "Organism/Name" equal to the species written by the user (input) then to calculate with "values.count" of the status column and finally to retrieve 'FTP Path'.
Here is the code that I could do but that does not work:

```
if (data.loc[(data["Organism/Name"]==species)
  print(Data['Status'].value_counts()) 
else:
    print("This species not found")

if (data.loc[(data["Organism/Name"]==species)
  print(Data['Status'].value_counts()) 
else:
    print(Data.get["FTP Path"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
import wget
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd    

URL='https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/GENOME_REPORTS/prokaryotes.txt'

data = pd.read_csv(wget.download(URL) , sep = '\t', header = 0)

species = input("Enter the bacteria species: ")   

if data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(species, case = False).any():

    print(data.loc[data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(species, case = False)]['Status'].value_counts())    
   
    FTP_list = data.loc[data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(species, case = False)]["FTP Path"].values

else:    
    print("This species not found")
```

To wite all the `FTP_Path` urls into a txt file, you can do this:

```
with open('/path/urls.txt', mode='wt') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(FTP_list))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, let me explain: in fact I want the value (the species) entered (input), to be used to see if it exists in the dataframe and then to retrieve all the lines that have this value, to do "value.count" against these lines. And also to retrieve in the FTP Path column all the urls to be able to download the nucleotide sequences please

Comment: Hi, the above code should be able to do that, you can take the input as you've mentioned while describing the question and then run the code I've written. Does it not work for you ? Please let me know which part doesn't work. The above code should do what you require.

Comment: The problem is that I still get the error message "species not found"

Comment: I actually wrote the part of the after you had taken the input from the user, you need to use your input part of the code as well. I've added the part in my answer. It will ask you for the 'species' name, you need to enter it and the code should work.

Comment: please can I ask you what ".unique" does. because for one species, you can have many FTP

Comment: I was assuming that you have multiple values for "FTP Path" and you only need the unique values ignoring the duplicated ones, thats the reason I had used it. `unique` would have returned a list of all the unique "FTP Paths" which had the `species` you entered.

Comment: so I use .get instead please?

Comment: Yes, I think you can. But that would return the entire column, the same result that the code I have written above would do.

Comment: for example i want to do if the user writes "klebsiella" i want to have a result with all the klebsiella for example klebsiella pneumoniae. i.e. after the input the program takes all the species that start with the input should i put * after species? pleaseee I'm sorry to take advantage of your kindness

Comment: So just for my understanding, the column "Organism/Name" has values like "klebsiella pneumoniae" ? And you would like to select all such columns which contain the word "klebsiella" ?

Comment: the () column has all the bacterial species, and klebsiella is a bacterial genus with several species like "klebsiella_pneumoniae" and "klebsiella_oxytoca" so for example I want when the user writes klebsiella it will have all the klebsiella please do I have to add "*" to say that it can have other characters after klebsiella for example

Comment: You'll have to use the string function 'startswith()', I'll make the edit in my answer for you.

Comment: thank you very much you are an angel. but unfortunately i still have the problem that for any species i write i always get "species not found" i think it is a problem with the if loop

Comment: If you could show me asample of  how your DataFrame looks I can help you better, I'm still trying to get an understanding of your DataFrame.

Comment: here is my complete script which will allow you to have everything. you can replace the commas with line breaks, because I can't put the script in normal format

Comment: import wget , import numpy as np , import pandas as pd  , URL='https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/GENOME_REPORTS/prokaryotes.txt' , wget.download(URL) , Data = pd.read_table("prokaryotes.txt", sep = '\t', header = 0)
print (type(Data)) , shape=Data.shape , print(shape) , Data= Data.replace (' ', '_', regex=True) , print (Data.head(n=2)) , colonne=Data.columns , print(colonne) , print("enter the name of the species, replacing spaces with _") , species=input()

Comment: if species in Data["#Organism/Name"]: , print(Data.loc[Data["#Organism/Name"].str.startswith(species)]['Status'].value_counts()) , print(Data.loc[Data["#Organism/Name"].str.startswith(species)]["FTP Path"])  ,  for url in Url: , wget.download(url)  , else : , print(species, "= not found")

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I will try my best to figure the problem out and get back to you.

Comment: I checked your data source and realised there were a few nuances which was causing the code to not work, I have tested this code with giving the input as `klebsiella`, it worked for me. Please run the code and let me know if it works as expected. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. what nuances please? i have run my script again but i still have "not found". did you change anything in the script to make it work for you ? did you manage to retrieve the footage with "FTP Path"  ? please

Comment: I have actually edited my answer and changed the code, can you please copy paste the code in my answer and run it ? For the input I have put `klebsiella` and it worked for me. At least did not give me the "not found" error. I haven't yet looked into the FTP_Path thing, I will check it once the code at least runs for you. Please let me after copy pasting the code and running it.

Comment: sincerely you are an angel. Thank you very much. Yes, it worked. But I think it's the wrong number of FTPs for "klebsiella" because just for klebsiella there are more than 10,000 FTPs Path please.

Comment: Yes I checked, there are 13216 values, you must be getting only a few outputs since your console does not print all of them, you can store them as a list if you want. So instead of writing the line to print all the FTPs you can write this: `FTP_list = data.loc[data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(species, case = False)]["FTP Path"].values`

Comment: Great thank you very much i thank you very much you have saved my life. and i noticed that i can even recover without changing the spaces by _ .

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm glad I could help. I would really appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted or upvote the answer, just keeping up with the StackOverflow culture :)

Comment: Yes of course I'll do that right away. But I have one last little question please with the temrinal I have this command from FTP Path I managed to get the sequences "IFS=$'\n'; for NEXT in $(cat urls.txt); do wget "$NEXT"; done" having downloaded all the FTP Path in a urls.txt file. I want to add a line to the code you made that allows me to have the sequences please

Comment: Sure, so let m understand correctly. You need to store all the FTP_Path urls in a .txt file line by line. Right ?

Comment: par exemple avec le fichier "prokayotes.txt" que vous avez du télécharger en exécutant le script, il y a des commandes sur le terminal qui permet d'avoir un fichier avec les urls.txt pour les génomes complet (juste pour un exemple klebsiella et complete genome ) :
grep "Klebsiella pneumoniae" prokaryotes.txt \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{if($16=="Complete Genome"){print $21}}' \
    | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}{print $0,$NF"_genomic.fna.gz"}' \
    > urls.txt

Comment: désolé, mon français n'est pas très bon

Comment: then this command allows to download the sequences which have the sequences from the urls.txt file with the FTP path :IFS=$'\n'; for NEXT in $(cat urls.txt); do wget "$NEXT"; done

Comment: I have added the code to my answer to get you the .txt file containing all the FTP_Path urls, I hope it helps

Comment: I would like to ask the user: which format between _genomic.fna.gz or _protein.faa.gz 
THEN DOWNLOAD from the list of URLs. then download according to his choice. 

for example: I took an FTP Path here is a result to visualize the thing  : I would like to ask the user: which format between _genomic.fna.gz or _protein.faa.gz 
THEN DOWNLOAD from the list of URLs. then download according to his choice. 

for example: I took an FTP Path here is a result for you to see: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/240/185/GCA_000240185.2_ASM24018v2

Comment: The link is not opening in my Safari browser for some reason. I'm sorry I sill don't understand what is required completely. Which column would I get the format from ? And so you want to filter the DataFrame based on the bacteria species as well as the format ?

Comment: do you know if I can duplicate the last folder in the path please and add "_genomic.fna.gz" to it. pleaseee

for example how to change from this """ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3""""

 to: """ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3_genomic.fna.gz"""""

Comment: Yes you can change folder names in Python, but how are the folder names stored ? Do you want to add `_genomic.fna.gz` at the end of all the FTP_Path list that we returned ?